# Add Service Reference menu vanishes when upgrading project to .net 4.0.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service

Using Visual Studio 2010.  I have a class library with WCF service references.  The project is net 3.5.  If I right click | Properties | and change target framework to .net 4.0, it reloads the project and the Service References folder is still there in gray and supports Add Service Reference.  But when I select .net 4.0.3, and it reloads, the Service References folder is vanilla and has no support for adding Service References.  I diff'ed the project files and the only difference is the  tag, which was bumped from 4.0 to 4.0.3.

I tried what some people recommended by adding a ProjectTypeGuid to the project file and it does not work.  I've also deleted cache and suo files.  Still no luck.

Anyone have any idea why switching frameworks to 4.0.3 might nuke my ability to see service reference folders as such?

Update:  Interestingly, if I target the project to 4.0.3 Client Profile, the service references still works.  Only 4.0.3 Full is yanking my ability to add service references.